# Debian не запускается Google Chrome

Tags: debian

Устанавливал Google Chrome двумя путями:

- Качал с официального сайта .deb пакет и устанавливал при помощи `dpkg -i`.
- Добавлял гугловский репозиторий и качал при помощи `apt-get install`

В обоих случаях Google Chrome устанавливается, но не запускается! Ни через меню, ни через Alt + F2.

Почему так происходит  и как это исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить из командной строки, почитайте что пишет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, запускаю `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` - терминал просто молчит. Кстати, может дело в том, что я из под root'a сижу?

Comment: Под рутом вообще плохо сидеть, вне зависимости от этой конкретной проблемы. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я в линуксе всего два дня, так что `sudo` не настроил и погнал под `su` все устанавливать... Теперь не хочу возвращаться и заново все переделывать :).

Comment: Все установленные приложения будут доступны и обычному пользователю. Что отличается - содержимое `.profile`, `.bashrc` и прочих файлов, следовательно и окружение. Но и это можно перенести, если вы там что-то уже настроили. Пока не поздно, создавайте себе обычного пользователя с sudo-правами и переходите на него.  )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, установил Flash Player - Iceweaser нормально заработал, надобность в Google Chrom'e отпала. А можно как-то одним махом все перенести на моего пользователя? Понастраивал  - это громко сказано :). Настроил звук, менюшку, установил firefox, adobe flash player и все :).

Comment: Купите windows и подобные проблемы отпадут сами собой.

Comment: @Sergey, а покупать-то зачем? :D

Comment: Гордится лицензией. Не париться со взломом активации. Обновления. Пиратская наверняка не обновляется. Это я про седьмую версию, если что. А покупать действительно не обязательно. Можно позаимствовать корпоративную у знакомого сисадмина.

Comment: @Sergey Я как-то слабо себе представляю, что человек, который освоил линукс, купит себе винду и будет этим гордиться. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

скорее всего, вы выполнили «графический вход» от имени рядового пользователя (и это не просто нормально, а «так и надо делать»), и пытаетесь запустить [x-клиента](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#.D0.9A.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82-.D1.81.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B2.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C_.D0.B8_.D1.81.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.B2.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B7.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8C) от имени другого пользователя. что по умолчанию невозможно — клиент не сможет подсоединиться к вашему экземпляру x-сервера.

«нормальный» x-клиент сообщит об этом:

```
$ su - пользователь
$ xeyes
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

а тот, который вы запускали, видимо, либо «не хочет» об этом сообщать, либо всё-таки подключился к x-серверу, но не к тому экземпляру, работу которого вы наблюдаете в данный момент на экране.

---

работать надо продолжать под рядовым пользователям, получая root-овые привилегии (с помощью программ `su` или, лучше, `sudo`) только для решения административных задач: конфигурирования системы, установки/удаления пакетов и тому подобного.